# Fill NSDictionary with JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

Iam new in iOS development .
I want to fill this json

```
"{
    "form_name":"login_form_mobile",
    "user_login":"mark wallet",
    "password":"123456",
    "dispatch":{"auth.login":"Sign in"}
}
"
```

into a NSDictionary to use it in post for a URL using AFNetworking.

I fill the dictionary like this

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"login_form_mobile",@"form_name",@"markwallet",@"user_login",@"123456",@"password",@"{ \" auth.login \" : \" Sign in \" }",@"dispatch", nil];
```

Now i have two problems
1-The \" in before and after auth.login is shown as it i want to show the Double quotes only.
BTW i tried to make a nested Dictionary this solved the first problem but for the second one problem not.
2-When i run the app. and see how the dictionary is filled it is shown like this

```
 {
    dispatch = "{ \" auth.login \" : \" Sign in \" }";
    "form_name" = "login_form_mobile";
    password = 123456;
    "user_login" = markwallet;
}
```

a-There is equal between the key and its value and i need it : not = 
b-some words doesnt have "" like password , 123456 and markwallet . i dont know why 
c-Also i dont know why dispatch and it value go in the first.

EDIT:

I used this new code.

```
NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Sign in",@"auth.login", nil];

NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"form_name",@"user_login",@"password",@"dispatch",nil];

NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"login_form_mobile",@"markwalletz",@"123456",dic,nil];

NSMutableDictionary * params1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
params1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
```

But when i see params1 value in the debug

```
{
    dispatch =     {
        "auth.login" = "Sign in";
    };
    "form_name" = "login_form_mobile";
    password = 123456;
    "user_login" = markwalletz; }
```

And this is differs from the one i need as stated at the top of the question
And when i send a request with this dictionary it replies BAD Request.

Comment: You should take a step back and understand what the difference between a JSON string and a parsed in-memory representation (dictionary, array) is.

Comment: could you declare more please ?!

Comment: Other than the different user name, the first and last view above are equivalent.  If you're getting "bad request" then likely there is some other cause, perhaps a translation problem in transmission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several things you need to understand:

- When you NSLog an NSDictionary, it does not display JSON syntax.  Yes, it superficially looks like JSON, but, as you noted, not all character strings are quoted (only those with blanks or odd characters get quotes) and an `=` is used instead of `:`.  This is because it's a `description` of the NSDictionary object, not a JSON translation.
- And, on the other hand, just because stuff looks the same between JSON and an NSDictionary does not make it the same.  Your `"dispatch":{"auth.login":"Sign in"}` entry represents a second NSDictonary as the value of the key "dispatch".  You cannot create that second dictionary simply by making the characters look like the JSON/`description` representation.  Rather, you have to (as a separate conceptual step) create that one-element dictionary and then insert it as an object in the outer dictionary.
- One place where NSDictionary and JSON *are* the same is that neither an NSDictionary nor a JSON "object" maintains the order of the key/value pairs it contains.  So don't expect to see the values in the same order in one version vs the other.

Comment: And I should add that the `description` of an NSArray looks sorta like a JSON array, except that `()` is used instead of `[]`, and the previously noted difference in quoting character strings.

Comment: Hello,
AM sorry but i tried to add the another dictionary of the key dispatch and its value to the old dictionary . but i tried several ways and i failed. could you tell me how. because i already make nsjsonserialization for the first part . and then i want to add this key and its value.
Could you help me how?

Comment: Also in some ways that i tried still dispatch goes in the first key. because it sorts it alphabetically . i dont know why

Comment: Replace this -- `@"{ \" auth.login \" : \" Sign in \" }"` -- with a pointer to the inner NSDictionary, which you create with another `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys` call.

Comment: Re-read point 3 above.  The order of the key/value pairs in a listing of an NSDictionary is random, and similarly the order in JSON is undefined/irrelevant.  Don't worry that the order is not the same as the order you inserted things.

Comment: the problem is sign in is and object for auth.login also ?
i think it is like a nested dictionary !!

Comment: YES, it's a nested dictionary.  Create the inner dictionary first, then include it in the outer one.

Comment: {
    dispatch =     {
        "auth.login" = "Sign in";
    };
    "form_name" = "login_form_mobile";
    password = 123456;
    "user_login" = markwalletz;
}
This what i see in the debug.
And this is what it should be
"{
    "form_name":"login_form_mobile",
    "user_login":"markwalletz",
    "password":"123456",
    "dispatch":{"auth.login":"Sign in"}
}
"
The response is BAD Request . So what do you think is wrong . am sorry but i must end this task 2day.
MY code is
 NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Sign in",@"auth.login", nil];

Comment: NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"form_name",@"user_login",@"password",@"dispatch",nil];
    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"login_form_mobile",@"markwalletz",@"123456",dic,nil];
    NSMutableDictionary * params1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    params1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

Comment: Edit your original question with new code, so it's formatted.

Comment: I edited the question please if you can say to me what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `NSJSONSerialization` class. Methods in this class will convert JSON into the appropriate objects (e.g NSDictionary, NSArray), and vice versa. See the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details.

**Added:**

For example:

```
NSString *jsonString = ... // Whatever your JSON is
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *d = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
```

What you get is a dictionary, `d`, that contains all the keys and their values as described in the JSON (assuming the JSON represented a dictionary). JSON data can represent an array of objects too. It's all quite flexible. I suggest reading the references documentation and search here for other examples using `NSJSONSerialization`. There are surely some good ones.

Comment: Am sorry Mark but i dont know how to do this . Do you mean to make NSData with the data i need and then put it in a JSON . and then convert it to NSDictionary.
And if so could you please give me the code.

Comment: Added an example. Hopefully that is helpful. Search here as well for more examples. Like Google, StackOverflow is your friend. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The "jsonString" variable should be formed like:

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"form_name\":\"login_form_mobile\",\"user_login\":\"mark wallet\",\"password\":\"123456\",\"dispatch\":\{\"auth.login\":\"Sign in\"}}";
```

Then, using the code above:

```
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments 
                                                  error:nil];
NSLog(@"DIC %@",dic);
```

will output:

```
DIC {
dispatch =     {
    "auth.login" = "Sign in";
};
"form_name" = "login_form_mobile";
password = 123456;
"user_login" = "mark wallet";
}
```

Comment: Enta Prince habeby <3

Answer (score 0):

If your json string is in a NSString variable called "jsonString":

```
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                    options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments 
                                                      error:nil];
```

So your "dic" variable will have the parsed json.

Comment: This is good i tried it and it works but the when i see what is inside the dic it shows that it is nill